# Installing PL/Ruby for PostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: ruby, postgresql, makefile, compilation

I have a problem installing PL/Ruby for PostgreSQL 8.4 on Windows XP

PostgreSQL 8.4 is installed and working OK
Ruby-186-27 is installed and working OK
I have MinGW installed and I'm using MSYS as the command line shell
I have downloaded plruby-0.5.3 and unzipped.

My PostreSQL is in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4
I've created a record in MSYS fstab file
c:/Progra~1/PostgreSQL/8.4 /usr/local/pgsql

I've tried calling the makefile as follows:

Running the following from the plruby-0.5.3 directory
ruby extconf.rb --with-pgsql-dir=/usr/local/pgsql

I've also tried running with
   --with-pgsql-include=/usr/local/pgsql/include
   --with-pgsql-include=/usr/local/pgsql/include/server
and also variations on the above i.e. using MSDOS Commands, using environment variables to pass file path, using MS DOS style directory names

The response I always get is:

have_header: checking for catalog/pg_proc.h... --------------------------- no

and then something like
"cl -nologo -E -I. -I"c:/Program Files/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32" -I. -Ic:/Progra~1/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/server -MD -Zi -O2b2xg- -G6 conftest.c -P"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1. #include 
/* end */

I'm getting pretty much the same output each time, I've checked and the pg_proc.h file is indeed in c:/Progra~1/PostgreSQL/8.4/include/server in sub-directory catalog

I've tried googling for an answer and it seems that quite a few people have had a problem with compiling Ruby shared libary on Windows in general with this type of issue, and others had issues creating PL/Ruby but I haven't found an answer anywhere on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to give.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you're trying to run something based on autoconf using the MSVC compiler. Last I checked, that was not supported by autoconf. I think autoconf requires mingw and gcc, not MSVC.

Comment: Thanks very much that sounds like a good tip - I will investigate and try the compile with gcc & mingw